# Laravel - Eager Loading BelongsToMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading, has-and-belongs-to-many, laravel-relations

I have one to many relationship between two entities/tables.

[image]

```
    /**
     * Get all of the products.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->select(
            [
                'products.id',
                'products.title',
                'products.sku',
                'automation_products.automation_id as auto_id',
                'display_order',
            ]
        )->orderBy('display_order');
    }
```

When I want eager load this relationship, it seems like there are duplicate queries running in the background. I use this code to eager load my relation:

```
    $automation = \App\Models\Automation::with('products')->whereId(1)->get()->first();
    dump($automation->products()->get());
    dump($automation->products()->get());
    dump($automation->products()->get());
```

is there something I am missing?

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: why do you think they run?

Comment: they are running, perfectly fine, Please don't get confused with the variable name,  the question is mainly around the query being executed again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager loading load relation into model property.

You can access this property like `$automation->products` - no matter how many times she is called - query will be executed **ONE** time with eager load.

But, when you call like `->products()->get()` - eloquent execute query because you tell "`get()` relation `products()` NOW"

Comment: it returns `null`  when ever i do $automation->products

Comment: Found out the relationship name must be the same as the table name, Thanks for help

Comment: that's not true